# ui.table.Table does not rerender rows when scrolling

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I got a ui.table.Table that wont render correctly when i'm scrolling to new items or changing filters so new data is filled to the table.
The initial visible rows (8) renders just as they should. I got a formatter that are hidding input fields, coloring background of cells and so on, needles to say, it's a big formatter (See code example).

I'm not sure what more i can provide beside the code examples, but let me know if you need any info to make it more clear.

Any input is welcome since i'm at a full stop, no ideas are stupid :-)

**Bonus info:**

- The applications is being developped in version 1.38.
- Table rows is bound in controller

**The XML code:**

```
                <t:Table id="tableLaunch" visible="true" columnMove="false" selectionMode="None" columnHeaderHeight="40px" fixedColumnCount="6" sort="onTableSort" class="tableLaunch" rowHeight="30px" 
                     visibleRowCountMode="Fixed"  enableBusyIndicator="true" noData="Select filters" visibleRowCount="8" threshold="5">
                <t:footer>
                    <Toolbar class="sapMTBHeader-CTX SPDToolbarExceptions">
                        <ToolBarSPacer/>
                        <Button id="btnResetInput" text="Reset" enabled="false" press="onResetChanges"/>
                        <Button id="btnSaveInput" text="Save" enabled="false" press="onSaveChanges"/>
                    </Toolbar>
                </t:footer>
                <t:columns>
                    <t:Column width="200px" sortProperty="AccountS" resizable="false" sorted="true">
                        <Text text="Customer"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Text text="{AccountS}"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="100px" sortProperty="Theme" resizable="false">
                        <Text text="Theme"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Text text="{Theme}"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="100px" sortProperty="Product" resizable="false">
                        <Text text="Product"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Text text="{Product}"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="100px" sortProperty="Item" resizable="false">
                        <Text text="Material Number"  maxLines="2" />
                        <t:template>
                            <Text text="{Item}"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="150px" sortProperty="CellText" resizable="false">
                        <Text text="Description"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Text text="{KeyFigureText}"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="55px" sortProperty="CasePack" resizable="false">
                        <Text text="Case Pack" maxLines="2"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Text text="{CasePack}"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>

                    <!--Table split at weeks -->

                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue1', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue2', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue3', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue4', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue5', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue6', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text  textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue7', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue8', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue9', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue10', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text  textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue11', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue12', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue13', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue14', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue15', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue16', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue17', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue18', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue19', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue20', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue21', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue22', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue23', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue24', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue25', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue26', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue27', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue28', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue29', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue30', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue31', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue32', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue33', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue34', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue35', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue36', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue37', formatter:'customFormatter.formatCells'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="57px" hAlign="Center" resizable="false">
                        <Text textAlign="Center"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Input value="{path: 'KeyFigureValue38', formatter:'customFormatter.formatRow'}" liveChange="onInputLiveChange" class="input--padding" editable="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                </t:columns>
            </t:Table>
```

**The formatter code;**

```
sap.ui.define([], function () {
var customFormatter = {
    formatCells: function (value) {
        return Math.floor(value);
    },
    formatRow: function () {
        var oBindingContext = this.getBindingContext();

        if (oBindingContext !== null) {
            var iPreWeeks = 5;
            var iPostWeeks = 7;
            var iCurrentWeek = new Date(Date.now()).getWeekNumber();
            var iLaunchWeek = new Date(oBindingContext.getObject().LaunchDate).getWeekNumber();
            var aWeekCells = this.getParent().getCells().slice(6);
            var iSelectedWeek = new Date(this.getModel("launchViewModel").getProperty("/selectedLauncDate")).getWeekNumber();
            var iLaunchWeekCell = (iLaunchWeek - iSelectedWeek) + 8;
            var iThisWeekCell = (iCurrentWeek - iSelectedWeek) + 8;
            //Enables colums after this week and disables before
            if (iThisWeekCell >= 0 && iThisWeekCell <= 38) {
                aWeekCells.slice(iThisWeekCell).forEach(item => item.setEditable(true));
                if (iThisWeekCell > 0) {
                    aWeekCells.slice(0, iThisWeekCell).forEach(item => item.setEditable(false));
                }
            }

            if (iLaunchWeekCell < 0) {
                iLaunchWeekCell = 52 + iLaunchWeekCell;
            }
            var iPreWeekFirstCol = (iLaunchWeekCell - iPreWeeks);
            if (iPreWeekFirstCol < 0) iPreWeekFirstCol = 0;

            if (iLaunchWeekCell >= 0) {
                aWeekCells[iLaunchWeekCell].setVisible(true);
                if ($(aWeekCells[iLaunchWeekCell].getDomRef()).length === 0) {
                    aWeekCells[iLaunchWeekCell].onAfterRendering = function () {
                        $(this.getDomRef()).parent().parent().addClass("launchCell--background-color");
                    }
                } else {
                    $(aWeekCells[iLaunchWeekCell].getDomRef()).parent().parent().addClass("launchCell--background-color");
                }
            }
            //Color the pre weeks
            if (iLaunchWeekCell > 0) {
                aWeekCells.slice(iPreWeekFirstCol, iLaunchWeekCell).forEach(function (item) {
                    $(item.getDomRef()).parent().parent().addClass("preLaunchCell--background-color");
                    if ($(item.getDomRef()).length === 0) {
                        item.onAfterRendering = function () {
                            $(this.getDomRef()).parent().parent().addClass("preLaunchCell--background-color");
                        }
                    } else {
                        $(item.getDomRef()).parent().parent().addClass("preLaunchCell--background-color");
                    }
                    item.setVisible(true);
                });
            }
            //Color the post weeks
            if (!((iLaunchWeekCell - iPostWeeks) > aWeekCells.length)) {
                if ((iLaunchWeekCell + 1) < 0) {
                    var tempILaunchWeekCell = 0;
                } else {
                    var tempILaunchWeekCell = iLaunchWeekCell + 1;
                }
                aWeekCells.slice((tempILaunchWeekCell), (iLaunchWeekCell + iPostWeeks + 1)).forEach(function (item) {
                    item.setVisible(true);
                    if ($(item.getDomRef()).length === 0) {
                        item.onAfterRendering = function () {
                            $(this.getDomRef()).parent().parent().addClass("postLaunchCell--background-color");
                        }
                    } else {
                        $(item.getDomRef()).parent().parent().addClass("postLaunchCell--background-color");
                    }
                });

                //Removes empty cells post launchspan
                aWeekCells.slice(iLaunchWeekCell + iPostWeeks + 1).forEach(item => item.setVisible(false));
            }
            //Empty cells pre launch span
            if (iPreWeekFirstCol > 0) {
                aWeekCells.slice(0, iPreWeekFirstCol).forEach(item => item.setVisible(false));
            }

        }
    }
};

window.customFormatter = customFormatter;

return customFormatter;
```

});

Comment: is it worked without formatter ?

Comment: yeah, evrything works fine without formatter.